# Unix cUrl cookie login to a .jsp servlet page, request and save file requested

Tags: bash, jsp, servlets, curl, request

I have tried to export a text file resulted by an request to a .jsp page with Java script enabled from Oracle BI Publisher framework with below command in Unix:

```
curl 'http://server/xmlpserver/report.xdo&_xt=New+Template+1&_xf=text'
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8'
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36'
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
-H 'Referer: http://server/xmlpserver/report.xdo'
-H 'Cookie: 
JSESSIONID=qq!11!22; ORA_XDO_UI=en_US; 
JSESSIONID=qq!11; oracle.uix=0^^GMT+3:00^p' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive'
--compressed -o test.txt
```

This command is 'copy as bash curl command' from Google Chrome debugger and work it but syntax command use id JSESSION in cookie who will expire.

I need to login on this .jsp page to generate cookie with JSESSION=qq!11!22 and JSESSION=qq!11 (see above cUrl syntax from Google Chrome).

For this I have used command:
curl -c cookies.txt -d "user=user&pass=pass" http://server/xmlpserver/login.jsp, and was generated only one "JSESSIONID=qq!11;".

I need to generate one more JSESSIONID=qq!11!22.

Thanks!

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: I need to generate JSSESIONID=qq!11!22 in cookie, was generated only JSSESIONID=qq!11. I can't make authentication for this. Curl command generated only "JSSESIONID=qq!11": curl -c cookies.txt -d "user=user&pass=pass" http://server/xmlpserver/login.jsp."